# Snowflake UDF is giving the error - Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am getting this error on doing a select on UDF - "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated", the parameters of the UDF are coming from the joins but not sure what is going wrong here. I have tried every suggestions but it is not working

It is SQL UDF - returning a varchar.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Not sure how you expect anyone to help you if you don’t include the code for the UDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the SQL UDF runs fine by itself. Then what will be happening is once you compose it into you main query you have forms a correlated sub-query that is not supported.

If you have “awesome complex magic” in the udf, change it be a udtf and return those results for all rows abd then join to that. This is the optimal join pattern in snowflake. Aka instead of row-by-row lookups. Build tables of as complete as possible data and join those together.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem with a scalar UDF returning varchar. I solved it by using MAX('string field or expression') in the select statement.